# How to do a date countdown (to a future date)?

Tags: datetime

How would one go about doing a date countdown (something like this: https://www.mupromo.com/?kbid=4722). I know I'd need to create a block...and I have boilerplate code for that, but I was wondering whether there's a module that already does something similar...or any other pointers you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/countdown) module has a drupal 6 & 7 version. This may work for you. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Adds a block titled "Countdown" to count the days, hours, minutes, and seconds since or until a specified event. Can configure to just show days, or days and hours, etc.
>
> See also:
>
> - [jQuery Countdown](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown).
> - [jQuery Countdown Timer](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown_timer).

Comment: Actually, this looks like exactly what I need! Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [Javascript Timer](http://drupal.org/project/jstimer) module or the [jQuery Countdown](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) module.  With either of these, you can add some code to the block to create your countdown.

[Javascript Timer](http://drupal.org/project/jstimer) has a Drupal 7 version, but [jQuery Countdown](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) currently does not.